# UICollectionView not resizing correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Trying to resize a UICollectionViewCell when a user presses it. At the moment, the cell resizes, but the other cells do not react to it. Here is a picture of the issue:

[image]

Here is the code I am using. I have a feeling the issue is with the invalidating, but I am not sure:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    UICollectionViewCell * cellToChangeSize = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // Avoid retain cycles


    void (^animateChangeWidth)() = ^()
    {
        CGRect frame = cellToChangeSize.frame;
        frame.size = CGSizeMake(300, 100);
        cellToChangeSize.frame = frame;
    };

    // Animate

    [UIView transitionWithView:cellToChangeSize duration:0.1f options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:animateChangeWidth completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];


    }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by extending *UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout* and implementing the *collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:* method: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:.

Instead of modifying the cell directly in *collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:*, I'd set the size in a model class perhaps, which you'll need to make available in the flow layout subclass.

Hope this helps.